# How can you turn off alternate screen in OSX's Terminal.app?

Tags: macos, terminal, terminal.app

altscreen is evil. If you don't know what I'm talking about, see [this page](http://fixlog.blogspot.com/2006/09/stop-gnome-terminal-screen-clear.html)
for visual demonstration.

Problem is, there doesn't seem to be a way to stop it with Terminal.app (under OSX), when you're not using  `screen`. Yes, you can edit terminfo definition, but that's rather blunt hammer. Plus that solution might break if Apple decides to update relevant term's definition in some patch. Is there some clean way to convince Terminal.app to block altscreen usage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

Terminal -> Preferences -> Settings -> Advanced

Change "Declare terminal as:" from `xterm-color` to `xterm` (or experiment with the other options...)

(worked for me with `man`, didn't try some of the others.)

Comment: Hmm. Looks like `TERM=xterm` instead of `xterm-color` does the trick *and* it doesn't cause colors to go away :) Let me play with it a bit more, to see whether there are any gotchas with that.

Thanks!

Comment: Note that this is somewhat accidental and won't solve the problem on Mac OS X Lion 10.7. The `xterm` terminfo file uses the latest, greatest escape sequences to switch to/from the alternate screen buffer, which Terminal didn't support prior to Lion, so it did nothing. However, Lion Terminal is now substantially more compatible with Xterm, including support for these specific escape sequences, so it will start working again. The terminfo `xterm1` is specifically designed to disable alternate screen switching, so you could use that instead.

Comment: Lion's terminal now supports this natively in any case: http://ell.io/U27h

Comment: @elliottcable, the "Show/Hide Alternate Screen" menu item does not directly address this issue. It doesn't suppress the terminal control sequences, it merely gives the user the ability to manually switch which screen they're currently viewing. As in xterm, this is primarily to enable users to view and copy text from the alternate screen after a full-screen program has exited. If you're motivated to do so, you can also use it to switch screens after each time a full-screen program switches screens, but it's probably going to be annoying to someone who thinks the alternate screen is evil.