# Getting LESS to return back to command line if a short file is displayed

Tags: linux, command-line, less

Is there a command line option that will allow `less` to return to the command line if there are not sufficient lines in the file to warrant paging.

Sure I have seen it in the past but can't find the option in help.

Comment: To summarize the below answer's and comments: `less -FX` works. It produces a behavior similar to that of `more` for short files.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

See manpage:

> -F or --quit-if-one-screen
>
> Causes less to automatically exit if the entire file can be displayed on the first screen.

Comment: +1 - Goes off and aliases `less` to `less -F`

Comment: Not sure I see the point of -F by itself as (at least on my Linux) doesnt display any of the file. But combined with -X it does what I want. Thanks.

Comment: The different behaviors are explained in this SU question and answer and even more in the blog linked from there.

http://superuser.com/questions/134598/how-can-you-turn-off-alternate-screen-in-osxs-terminal-app

http://fixlog.blogspot.com/2006/09/stop-gnome-terminal-screen-clear.html