# Unix text viewer that doesn't take away from the flow?

Tags: unix, text-editors

Sorry for the awkward phrasing of the title but I was wondering if there was a text viewer (like more or less) that takes you away from the command prompt when you're viewing a doc and then when you quit the viewer, you're right back at the last command you typed. Like how vim functions. So I guess vim would work but I was wondering if there was another text viewer that's simpler.

Comment: Like @garyjohn's answer I had thought I had got this functionality with less but on my work computer, it's not working like I want it to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I think what you're referring to is the use by some programs such as Vim of the terminal's alternate screen. I'm using `less` version 429 in a GNOME Terminal 2.26.3.1 under KDE on a Fedora 11 system. When I clear the `LESS` environment variable before running `less`, e.g.,

```
$ ls | LESS= less
```

then quit `less`, the screen is restored to the state it was in before running `less`. So, check the value of `LESS` and see if it contains something that's interfering with that behavior.

Comment: i think that's the problem! but how do I check what's in the LESS environment variable that's interfering with this behavior?

Comment: Executing `echo $LESS` will show you what's in the variable, then `man less` will show you what each of those letters means. `less --help` will give you more terse explanations. I think the option/letter controlling this behavior is `X`, which "Disables sending the termcap initialization and deinitialization strings to the terminal. This is sometimes desirable if the deinitialization string does something unnecessary, like clearing the screen."

Comment: when I `echo $LESS` I just get a blank line :(

Comment: It may be your terminal rather than `less` that's controlling this, although that doesn't explain `vim`'s ability to control it. With an `xterm`, you can hold the Ctrl key while pressing the middle mouse button and see a menu that includes "Enable Alternate Screen Switching". That should be checked for `less` to work as you'd like it to. This may also be controlled by the `titeInhibit` X resource. I don't know how it is controlled in any other terminal type, but if you're not using an `xterm`, maybe that will give you some terms to look for.

Comment: i'm using Mac OS X Terminal :(

Comment: I don't have access to a Mac at the moment, but a quick Google search revealed a related discussion here, http://superuser.com/questions/134598/how-can-you-turn-off-alternate-screen-in-osxs-terminal-app, where the object was turn this feature *off*. Maybe you can use that info to turn yours *on*.

Comment: thank you for that but I just tested it on a freebsd machine and even for vim, when i quit out of it, it leaves the vim screen and then just inserts a command line prompt at the bottom.

Answer (score 3):

Try **nano** and **pico**.

IIRC, they don't mess with the contents of your session. They are also way simpler. If you don't need to edit and only want to output the files, then you just need

'cat *filename*'

and it won't even leave your shell to create any fullscreen viewer environment such as your experience with vi

Answer (score 1):

There is a command generally available called `view` which basically just runs vi/vim in read-only mode.